# Using org.openrdf.rio.trig.TriGWriter to create a SPARQL update

Tags: scala, sparql, sesame

I'm using org.openrdf.rio.trig.TriGWriter to create a SPARQL update query. My query needs to be of the following format:

```
PREFIX ....
PREFIX ....
insert data{
    graph <....../id>{}
    graph <....../id>{}
    graph <....../id>{}  
}
```

but what I'm getting now is this:

```
PREFIX ....
PREFIX ....
insert data{
    graph <....../id>
    @prefix ...
    @prefix ...
    {....}

    graph <....../id>
    @prefix ...
    @prefix ...
    {....}

    graph <....../id>
    @prefix ...
    @prefix ...
    {....}
}
```

The prefixes are related to TriGWriter.startRDF() and TriGWriter.endRDF() calls. I'd like to suppress all lines that are @prefix. I hope there is a clean way of doing this without getting them out once they are already there. I'm looking at the TriGWriter.closeActiveContext() call, but I'm not getting good results. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the code producing my sparql:

```
def rdfWriter = new org.openrdf.rio.trig.TriGWriter(updateWriter);
rdfWriter.startRDF();
rdfWriter.handleNamespace("dc","http://purl.org/dc/terms/");
rdfWriter.handleNamespace("mrss","http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
rdfWriter.handleNamespace("xsd","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#");
rdfWriter.handleNamespace("owl","http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#");
rdfWriter.handleNamespace("sesame","http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#");
rdfWriter.endRDF(); 

updateWriter.getBuffer().setLength(resetLength);
it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) 
{                                   
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    rdfWriter.startRDF();   
    """GRAPH <${camelContext.getRegistry().lookup('context')}content/${pair.getKey()}>""".writeTo(updateWriter);                                
    def graph = pair.getValue();  
    graph.each{ 
        rdfWriter.handleStatement(it);
    }
    rdfWriter.endRDF(); 
}
updateWriter.append("${lsp} }; ${lsp}");
```

Answer (score 1):

The TriGWriter is really not designed for this kind of thing. It writes TriG documents, not SPARQL update statements, and while they are superficially similar, syntax-wise, they are not the same (as you have found out). I think you might be better off to roll your own simple `RDFHandler` implementation, in which you really only need to implement `handleStatement`.

However, what you *can* do if you insist on using TriGWriter, is to create a subclass of TriGWriter in which you override the `handleNamespace` method, to make it a simple no-op. That way, the writer will never write prefix mappings and also will never use prefixed names instead of IRIs.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciate your input. I'll try implementing my own handler.

Comment: @user2917629 ProTip: create a subclass of RDFHandlerBase. That way you don't have to provide implementations for every single method, you can just override the ones that you want to modify.

Comment: Yes, most certainly. Thank you :)